# replace command not working in PIG

Tags: regex, replace, apache-pig

My input is

```
(main_1077B13E4299_Logs_03-23-15-10-23AM,imagename:SR150BN_1.3.4p6s2_VBNse,VERSION=1.3.4.6,BRANCH=2183d95)
(main_1077B13E42C9_Logs_03-21-15-06-52AM,imagename:SR150BN_1.3.4p6s2_VBNse,VERSION=1.3.4.6,BRANCH=2183d95)
```

and the needed output is

```
(main_1077B13E4299_Logs_03-23-15-10-23AM,SR150BN_1.3.4p6s2_VBNse,1.3.4.6,2183d95)  
(main_1077B13E42C9_Logs_03-21-15-06-52AM,SR150BN_1.3.4p6s2_VBNse,1.3.4.6,2183d95)
```

Replace didn't work. How can I do this?

Comment: I tried usingREPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(base,'BRANCH=',' '),'VERSION=',' '),'imagename:',' ')'

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this is what you want, but you didn't give any details:

`REPLACE(input, '([(,])\w+[:=]', '$1')`

This will remove any word and ":" or "=", following a paren or comma.